# Prove if a matrix A multiplied by its transpose is 0, then the matrix A is nule

Tags: matrices, transpose

if A is a matrix NxN prove that if A x A^t = matrix nule NxN 
so A is nule NxN

I'Have tried by the summation notation but nothing came

Comment: If you have studied determinants, it is known that $det(A) = det(A^T)$, and that $A$ is singular if and only if $det(A)=0$. Also, the determinant is multiplicative, i.e. $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$.

Comment: @Joshhh I thought this was about zero-matrices versus non-zero matrices, not about singular matrices versus non-singular matrices. But maybe you're right.

Comment: I cant use determinants, the book im using just showed the basic properties of sum and multiplication

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What appears along the diagonal of $A A^T$?

Comment: considering the multiplication , the trace is zero

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa Not the trace. Not the _sum_ of the terms along the diagonal. The actual terms along the diagonal. What are they? How do they appear? What must happen for all of them to be $0$?

Comment: the diagonal of the multiplied is the square of each one of the diagonal elements of A right? if they are zero each element of diagonal of A is zero

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa No, that's not what the diagonal entries are. Take, say, $A = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. What are the diagonal entries of $AA^T$? Because they aren't $1^2$ and $4^2$. There is a bit more information about the matrix stuffed in there.

Comment: the diagonal element Cii of the diagonal of A.A^t is equal the sum of the squares of the line i from matrix A

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa Exactly. And if that is zero, what do you know about row $i$ of $A$?

Comment: omg, ive understandood if is the sum of squares is zero, and they are all >=0 each one of them must be zero. I love you guy. How do i see this in the beggining?

Comment: You mean how you can come up with something like this on your own? Practice. And trying out stuff: Don't be afraid of a bit of computing to get a feel for what the question is asking about, even if the question itself is entirely general and abstract.

Comment: thank you so much, how im new with this i felt a little ashamed by using 2x2 and 3x3 to see what happens, i thought i should only arrive the result from the letter

Comment: @LeoMartosBarbosa There is no reason to be ashamed of using small examples to check things. Of course, the final proof should only be using general dimensions and letters. But your own notes can have whatever you find helpful in them. Do you think you might understand better how to solve the problem if you calculate a couple of $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ examples? Then that's an entirely acceptable thing to do.

Comment: People who can solve problems like these using only letters and such can do so only because they have lots of practice, and already have a good feel for what's going on. So they don't have to do the $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ examples, because they have already done them many times.

Comment: It's probably worth remembering that the $i,j$ element of $AA^T$ is the dot product between row $i$ and row $j$ of $A$ (and hence the diagonal entries of $AA^T$ are the squared lengths of the corresponding rows of $A$). Similarly, the $i,j$ entry of $A^TA$ is the dot product between *columns* $i$ and $j$ of $A$.